# Melhorar desempenho de COUNT MySQL

Tags: mysql, aplicação-web, desempenho, cakephp-3

Tenho uma aplicação web que realiza diversas consultas, porém uma consulta de count está levando 2 segundos para buscar e retornar os dados para a aplicação. A minha tabela em que realizo o COUNT possui umas 230 mil linhas com umas 20 colunas, como posso otimizar essa consulta?

---

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE status = 1 AND category = 0;
```

---

Qual é a melhor maneira de realizar a contagem de dados em uma tabela com variação na query?

Quem puder me ajudar agradeço desde já!

Comment: Crie índices para as colunas de status e category

Comment: $result = mysql_query( "select count(id) as num_rows from myTable WHERE status = 1 AND category = 0" );

Comment: $row = mysql_fetch_object( $result );

Comment: $total = $row->num_rows;

Comment: fonte https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116824/whats-the-best-way-to-get-total-of-records-in-a-mysql-table-with-php

Comment: Esse `count(id)` considera eventuais `id`s nulos?

Comment: Provavelmente você não possui índices nessa coluna, 230mil registros não é um volume de dados considerável para uma consulta estar demorando.